# how to run base_local_planner and dwa_local_planner standalone?

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa-local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, all,

I am trying to run the navigational core move_base separately.
there are number of nodes to run before it functions properly.

among them, I cannot find any executable under base_local_planner and dwa_local_planner packages, i.e. I cannot 'rosrun xx_local_planner [executable]'.
how to run them as standalone nodes?

thanks

ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190749/how-to-run-base_local_planner-and-dwa_local_planner-standalone?/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_base is one node that loads planners using `pluginlib`. Planner classes follow the interfaces defined in `base_local_planner` and `base_global_planner`, but they don't (usually) directly publish or subscribe to anything.

If you REALLY want to run a planner on it's own, you can write a small c++ node that loads the plugin as a member variable, and sets up the publishers/subscriptions as necessary.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1